# How do I create a batch loop with commands in the list?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script with a for loop that contains commands in the list.  my problem is when i run commands with arguments it reads the space as a list deliminator.  I intend to have several commands in the list, but for now it is only 2. the %1 is the file to write the output to.

```
for %%G IN ("ipconfig /all" "net start") DO (
 echo %%G >> %1
 %%G >> %1 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
break>%1
for %%G IN ("ipconfig /all" "net start") DO (
 echo "%%~G"
 %%~G
)>>%1
```

use `%%~G` to dequote the token.